# How to create JSON object without using String?

Tags: java, android, json, string

I want to create an android application that uses an API to show some information on a listview. The problem I am facing is that the json file that I want to download is too big for String the object. My instructor told me that Android Studio somehow limited the size of the String. I get the error "constant string too long".
Is it possible for me to download that information as a json file (it is .geojson actually) and store it somewhere in the disk (actually I can download the file), and then parse it without using any String object by reading it from the file itself. OR Can you suggest another way of doing it since I am new in programming?

Comment: `Can you suggest another way of doing it` Yes Use [JsonReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) to parse JSON without holding it in String or StringBuffer

Comment: I would recommend you to break down such a huge information while retrieving from server (because you might not be displaying all at once) or download it by another way like any other file and read from that from local system using JsonReader.

Comment: Try https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: @UmaisGillani I can not break down the information because the information has tags in it and I am going to parse it as a complete file. Secondly, actually the information is not that huge maybe maximum 8 MB but in general around 6 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is that using simple JSON simple library in my project.
You can get it from [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/).
After I downloaded the JSON file to the storage, I parsed it by using the code below:

```
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = null;

    try {
        obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(directory of the folder + "/fileName.extension"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
```

Now you can use jsonObject as how you want.